# Undead Fortitude and multiple damage types

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, undead, zombies

So I know how Undead Fortitude works when it comes to the saving throw calculation (5+damage taken) but how exactly does it work against attacks that contain multiple damage types? Say we take 3 scenarios to compare (assuming damage total rolled is high enough and it doesn't crit):
A) 2d6 slashing damage from a Greatsword
B) 1d6 slashing and 1d6 fire damage
C) 1d6 slashing and 1d6 radiant

From how I read it I think A and B have the same outcome (CON save) and C just kills outright, but I'd like to make sure.

Comment: Related in [Multiple damage  types and death saves/massive damage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73928/is-damage-from-multiple-damage-types-cumulative-for-death-and-massive-damage)

Answer (score 2):

**You are reading it correctly.**

Assuming the damage comes from a single source, the feature Undead Fortitude only lets the undead make a Constitution saving throw if none of the damage was radiant (or a critical hit).

Therefore scenario C (1d6 slashing and 1d6 radiant) would kill the undead.

Comment: You are right here, but can you support this with the relevant rules?

Comment: I am searching, but I can't find any relevant rules. Neither anything that says that you can add the damage in any order you want, therefore making the radiant damage the one that actually reduces the undead to 0 hit points, nor anything that says that combined damage types classifies for specific damage type requirements.

Comment: I think it's hard to find a relevant rule because there is no reason to split different damage types into different damage sources.